# WCF  Dispose() Not Called With InstanceContectMode = PerSession

Tags: .net, wcf

In PerSession how do I get Dispose() on the service to fire?  In the code below Dispose() does not get called. Neither when I call .Close() nor if I let the session time out.

If I change the service to PerCall Dispose() is called (with each method call).  With PerSession I am getting a session (tested with serviceStartTime).

**Service**

```
[ServiceBehavior (InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MagicEightBallService : IEightBall, IDisposable
{
    private DateTime serviceStartTime;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Eightball dispose ... " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId.ToString());
    }
    public MagicEightBallService()
    {
        serviceStartTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Eightball awaits your question " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId.ToString() + " " + serviceStartTime.ToLongTimeString());
    }
    public string ObtainAnswerToQuestion(string userQuestion)
    {
        return "maybe " + OperationContext.Current.SessionId.ToString() + " " + serviceStartTime.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

**Client**

```
    using (EightBallClient ball = new EightBallClient())
    {    
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Your question: ");
            string question = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(question)) break;
            try
            {
                string answer = ball.ObtainAnswerToQuestion(question);
                Console.WriteLine("8-ball says: {0}", answer);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ball.ObtainAnswerToQuestion exception " + Ex.Message);
            }               
        }
        ball.Close();
     }
```

**Service-Contract**

```
[ServiceContract (SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IEightBall
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ObtainAnswerToQuestion(string userQuestion);

    [OperationContract]
    sDoc GetSdoc(int sID);

    DateTime CurDateTime();
}
```

**Host**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISampleService" 
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Message" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true"
                   inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                   enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MajicEightBallServiceLib.MagicEightBallService"
               behaviorConfiguration="EightBallServiceMEXBehavior" >
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISampleService"
                  contract="MajicEightBallServiceLib.IEightBall">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding ="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MagicEightBallService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>             
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EightBallServiceMEXBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

namespace MagicEightBallServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("**** Console Based WCF Host *****");

            using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MagicEightBallService)))
            {
                serviceHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is running");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your service contract also specified with `Session=true`? I think that's the only way the client knows to tell the server when it's done with a session.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Where would I put Session=true?  I tried SessionMode = SessionMode.Required but that did not help.

Comment: `[ServiceContract(Session = True)]` (I don't know this to be the answer I just know I always do this with my session-based services.)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I get a syntax error when I try to add Session = true but thanks

Comment: Do you tried to use another binding such as NetTcpBinding? wsHttpBinding supports sessions only with security and with reliable messaging

Comment: @Jehof security mode="Message"  It is getting a session. The ctor is only called at the begging of the session.  In Per Call the ctor is called with every method.  Tested it will a DateTime.Now in the ctor and it has the same DateTime for each method call in the session.  I have not tried NetTcpBinding.

Comment: And I set reliableSession enabled.  But even when it was false I was getting what appeared to be a valid session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Dispose()` method will be fired. The only question question is "When?".

Answer to that question depends on the service configuration.

There are several possible scenarios:

1. Session is not supported by binding
2. Normal session
3. Reliable session

`Dispose()` is fired when session is closed for `PerSession` context mode. So we need to check how long does session live in different scenarios.

For some configurations (for example default `BasicHttpBinding`) session is not started at all.  In case of session-less configuration  `PerCall` and `PerSession` context modes have no difference and  `Dispose` method will be called very soon after your main method executed.

When `Session` is Enabled it can be closed explicitly by client or by timeout. Normally it is controlled by client. Client initiates session before making first call to service and closes it when Client object is closed.

```
ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData(123));
proxy.Close();
```

`proxy.Close()` method above closes the session in server what in turn executes `Dispose()`.

Session management is a big performance driver because it requires additional calls between client and server to be performed.

So normally `Dispose` will be called when Client wants to close the session.

If client did not close session for any reason it will be closed by service host after certain period of time. That period is controlled by [Binding.ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx) property.
Default value for that property is 10 min.

Session will be closed and (`Dispose()` fired) if nobody sent request to server  with certain Session Id for 10 min. 
This default timeout can be changed by setting `receiveTimeout` to some shorter value in web.config.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" receiveTimeout="00:00:05">
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

[ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout.aspx) is additionally checked when Reliable session is enabled. It is also defaulted to 10 min.

It works as expected in self-hosted and IIS-hosted services.

Try to update your client code as follows to test:

```
using (EightBallClient ball = new EightBallClient())
{    
    ball.ObtainAnswerToQuestion("test");
    ball.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please see my code.  I am calling ball.Close(); and Dispose() is not firing.  If I let the session time out Dispose() is not called.  Is ball.Close(); not closing the proxy?

Comment: I tested that before posting an answer. Everything I told is true for service hosted by IIS using *.svc. How do you host your code?

Comment: I am hosting in a simple console app.  I will post the whole host.  ANd thanks

Comment: @Blam I just checked console - everything works great. Check my update in answer. Are you sure that you leave loop when you test? Close is your code is called only after all questions are asked.

Comment: Tried that and still no Dispose().  Yes I am sure it is leaving the loop and exiting. And like I said I have let it time out.  Set it back to PerCall and it does call Dispose().   I am on Vista.  I can test on Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: Finally ran a test on Windows 2008 Server and .Dispose() is called with PerSession (but SessionID is not available in Dispose).  On my Vista it was not called.  Thanks again